# Why doesn't Vte.Terminal work?

Tags: python, bash, gtk3, gobject

So I have started to mess with the gi module for python3, and have had a problem with Vte.Terminal. I have looked at other posts and have gotten this to execute a shell script:

```
def initWidgets(self):
    self.terminal = Vte.Terminal()
    self.layout.pack_start(self.terminal, True, True, 0)

    self.terminal.fork_command_full(
            Vte.PtyFlags.DEFAULT, #default is fine
            os.environ['HOME'], #where to start the command?
            ["/bin/sh"], #where is the emulator?
            [], #it's ok to leave this list empty
            GLib.SpawnFlags.DO_NOT_REAP_CHILD,
            None, #at least None is required
            None,
            )

    command = '"/home/User/Dropbox/GTK+ 3/testScript.sh"'
    length = len(command)
    self.terminal.feed_child(command, length)
```

But I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Terminal' object has no attribute 'fork_command_full'
```

I realize this means that the function 'fork_command_full' has been removed, but no where in the documentation can I find a replacement or an alternative way of doing it. Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. This is what my testScript.sh looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Working!
```